# What is the best way to get the x Blitz achievements?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

Anyone got these achievements for all difficulties? As the title says, what is the best way to defeat an AI in under five minutes?

Comment: Cannon Rush ;-)

Comment: I think I am gonna try the cannon rush. A friend of mine tried early pool and failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cannon rush works reliably against Insane AI.  Works best against enemy Protoss; creep and fast zerglings makes things complicated.  Blistering sands is good.  If you get it for Insane, you'll simultaneously get it for lower AI levels.

- 9 Pylon
- Send probe, avoid enemy scouts
- 11 Forge
- 12 Proxy pylon
- 12 2x cannons
- 12 Pylon
- 12 Keep building cannons

You should get 'GG' at 4:30.

Comment: This strategy worked for me. It took a few tries for me to get the insane achivment :P

Comment: Blizzard updated the Very Hard/Insane AI to *aggressively* defend vs. cannon rushes. Now as soon as you drop a pylon anywhere in their base they'll send workers to kill it off.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah. I got it on insane, ZvT (i was playing zerg). An early pool and then zergling rush should do it.

When i got into the Terran base, there was an scv building a barracks. Killed that SCV, and the AI gave up. 8-D

Comment: How early pool is early? 6 pool?

Comment: Yeah. 6 pool it up

Answer (score 1):

You are going to want to 6-pool.  I don't even think you need gas for this type of push, and you might not even need the Queen.  Just get those lings in there base and micro a bit to take out any marines that pop out.

The A.I. will do some funky things with its drones to try to deal with the early rush, so constant ling pressure and you should be fine.

Remember insane A.I. gathers 7 minerals to your 5 minerals so it is critical you hit that supply line.

Comment: 6 pooling insane AI is not trivial.  I heard they patched it to counter popular cheeses, though i have no source.  I just tried to 6 pool and failed to get the blitz.

Comment: Not trivial, but can certainly be done using hotkeys and rally points. Don't cut back and forth from base to base. Only look at your enemy's base. Once you assign your hatchery to a control group, you can do everything you need to do to your base using only the keyboard.